# Haskell, How to use multiple Eq (Eq a, Eq b ) =>

Tags: haskell

I would like to use multiple times Eq, 
so that the second element of the first tuplet is from another type than the rest

**Wrong, but, it is the idea what I want**

> eg.  [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)] -> Bool   ---->   [(a, b)] -> [(a, a)] ->
>   Bool

**the code**

```
canColor ::  Eq a => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)] -> Bool
canColor _ [] = True
canColor xs ((x,y):rest) =
    if findNeighbour xs x == findNeighbour xs y
    then False
    else canColor xs rest

findNeighbour :: Eq a => [(a, a)] -> a -> Maybe a
findNeighbour [] _ = Nothing
findNeighbour ((x,y):rest) z =
    if x == z
    then Just y
    else findNeighbour rest z
```

**The inputdata and expectation value**

```
Main> canColor [('a',"purple"),('b',"green"),('c',"blue")] [('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','a')]
True

Main> canColor [('a',"purple"),('b',"green"),('c',"purple")] [('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','a')]
False

Main> canColor [('1',"purple"),('2',"green"),('3',"blue")] [('1','2'),('2','3'),('3','1')]
True

**Main> canColor [('a', 4),('b',5),('c', 6 )] [('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','a')]
True

Main> colors [('a', 4),('b', 4 ),('c', 5 )] [('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','a')]
False**
```

Comment: `findNeighbour` seems to be `lookup` with its arguments swaped. Note that `lookup` allows for `(a,b)` instead of `(a,a)`. Does that help?

Comment: Haskell's type inference means many of these questions can be answered by just removing the type signatures and examining the function with `:t` in GHCi. (I.e. without the explicit type signature GHC will infer `canColor :: (Eq a, Eq b) => [(a,b)] -> [(a,a)] -> Bool`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply give them different type variables and require `Eq` for both. I think you are looking for this code:

```
canColor ::  (Eq a, Eq b) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, a)] -> Bool
canColor _ [] = True
canColor xs ((x,y):rest) =
    if findNeighbour xs x == findNeighbour xs y
    then False
    else canColor xs rest

findNeighbour :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> a -> Maybe b
findNeighbour [] _ = Nothing
findNeighbour ((x,y):rest) z =
    if x == z
    then Just y
    else findNeighbour rest z
```

or this more succinct and idiomatic code:

```
canColor ::  (Eq a, Eq b) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, a)] -> Bool
canColor xs = all (\(x,y) -> lookup x xs /= lookup y xs)
```